# What FLOSS DB design tool for Linux would you recommend?

Tags: database

I want to find a relational DB design tool for Linux, that could export DB schema for MySQL, SQLite and PostreSQL at least. And it should be handy, of course. Good-looking GUI is also a plus ;-) I use Gnome, but KDE tools are interesting too.

Comment: What *is* a "DB design tool"?

Comment: I'm not strong in terminology. Does DB modeling sound better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For MySQL there is [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/):

> MySQL Workbench is a cross-platform,
>   visual database design tool developed
>   by MySQL. It is the highly anticipated
>   successor application of the
>   DBDesigner4 project. MySQL Workbench
>   will be available as a native GUI tool
>   on Window, Linux and OS X.

Comment: Can I export SQL for SQLite and PostreSQL with MySQL Workbench? Because DBDesigner4, its predecessor, claimed it could.

Comment: It can be achieved with a plugin for SQLite: http://wb.mysql.com/?p=227. Still looking for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 10):

You can have a look at [WWW SQL designer](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/)

> WWW SQL Designer allows users to
> create database designs, which can be
> saved/loaded and exported to SQL
> scripts. Various databases and
> languages are supported. Ability to
> import existing database design.
>
> This tool allows you to draw and
> create database schemas (E-R diagrams)
> directly in browser, without the need
> for any external programs (flash). You
> only need JavaScript enabled. The
> Designer works perfectly in Mozillas
> (Firefox, Seamonkey), Internet
> Explorers (6, 7, 8), Safari and
> Operas. Konqueror works, but the
> experience is limited.

*Code license:       New BSD License*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [DBDesigner 4](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/index.php). Its a MySQL database design tool that also supports other database products like SQL Server, Oracle, SQL Lite and ODBC.

Its free, opensource (GPL), available for Linux/GNOME.

Some interesting features:

- If you are using a database not
  directly supported, you can create
  your own data type. Right click in
  the data type window and select
  Create New Datatype.
- You can connect to an existing database and it will import your model.

Comment: I've used this one a bunch of times and love it!

Comment: But isn't it the prototype of MySQL Workbench? EDIT: Yes, it is. "MySQL Workbench is a cross-platform, visual database design tool developed by MySQL. It is the highly anticipated successor application of the DBDesigner4 project."

Answer (score 2):

Try Knoda.  It's a database front-end that can be used to create, view, and modify many different types of databases.  You just need to install the relevant hk_clasess database drivers for the database you want to work with(e.g.MYSQL, SQLite, Postgresql and even Access (read only)).  What's nice about Knoda is that a) you can export and import from one database format to another and b) it has a visual query builder if you are not proficient in SQL.  Unfortunately, the package is not being maintained and so is no longer available in repositories of recent Ubuntu releases.  You can still install it from Lucid repository.